# Integration (differential equation)

Tags: integration, differential, homogeneous-equation

Does anyone know how to solve: $$(2x^2-xy)dx-(y^2+xy)dy=0$$
I solved that $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{(2x^2-xy)}{(y^2+xy)}$$

Then, I substituted $vx$ for $y$ and found that $$-\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{(v^2+v)dv}{(v^3+v^2+v-2)}$$ However, I don't know how to approach the integration in the right side. I even checked Symbolab and integration calculator, but most of these online resources weren't able to provide any aid in this problem.

Please help!

Comment: Are you sure if that's really your question?
Wolfram Alpha gives: $\int\frac{x^2 + x}{x^3 + x^3 + x - 2} dx = \sum_{({ω: 2 ω^3 + ω - 2 = 0})} \frac{ω^2 \log(x - ω) + ω \log(x - ω)}{6 ω^2 + 1} + C$

Comment: Yes, so I'm confused on how to approach the problem.

Comment: Well the original question was to solve for (2x^2-xy)dx-(y^2+xy)dy=0; however, I differentiated it and found this equation to integrate.

Comment: Write your DE as $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2x^2-xy}{y^2+xy}$. This is a homogeneous DE and can be solved via the substitution $y=vx$.

Comment: I did but then I would have to integrate (v^2+v)/(v^3+v^2+v-2) and I didn't know what to do from there.

Comment: This is not "complex integration" because it does not involving integrating a complex variable.  Thus the edit of the tag words.

Comment: Write in mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference